# After installing pytube it says its not installed

Tags: python, pytube

I am currently trying to make a YouTube video down loader, but when i imported a module it says its not installed while pip says its installed. I reinstalled python but still no luck and i couldn't find a fix online. I looked online to try and find a fix but couldn't find anything replicating my issue or they just reinstalled and it worked which i tried already

i am Also running python 3.10 on vs code and used the pip3 and normal pip to install and both said it was installed so my question is why is the module saying its not installed and is there any fix? (any help appreciated)

Comment: Can you show us the error? Maybe an image or copy-paste the error

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities for this:
First confirm the version information

1. Use Win + R to enter CMD, and then enter Python in the window to view the python version. You can update this screenshot to the problem later
2. Then open your editor, such as vscode, click the python version in the lower right corner (or in the lower left corner), and check to see if you have multiple Python installed. This causes the module to be installed on python that you don't often use

Comment: Thank you i think it was from multiple pythons

Answer (score 0):

The fix for the issue is that multiple pythons where installed so removing both and re downloading one fixed it for me, i think one was from Microsoft store